# Stata: export regression output to Latex with several datasets

Tags: loops, stata

I have a bunch of datasets in the same folder and I would like to run the very same regression for every dataset. Also, I would like to export the respective regression output in .tex format for every dataset. This is what I tried:

```
ssc inst fs, replace
fs *.dta 
foreach f in `r(files)' {
use "`f'" 
local newname : subinstr local f ".dta" ".tex"
reghdfe y x1 x2 x3, absorb(fe1 fe2) cluster(fe1 fe2)
outreg2 using `newname', replace ctitle ((1)) addtext(fe1, YES, fe2, YES) adjr2
}
```

I get the error *invalid 'Export'*. The regression is run, but it seems the outreg2 is not working. I don't see my mistake, who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess: the command beginning

```
outreg2 using `newname'
```

should begin

```
outreg2 using "`newname'"
```

if any filename in question includes any spaces.  See [U] 11.6 in [the Stata manuals](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u11.pdf).

Comment: The spaces in the filename were the problem, indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see two weird things here

- should not you use `use f, replace`?
- is `outreg2` compatible with `reghdfe`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should write use "`f'", clear. Thanks. And yes, it is compatible.